# How can I use the number entered by the user as a variable?

Tags: r, function, vector, statistics, computer-science

I have 8 variables as Var1-Var8. I want to find cross-product between 2 of them by user's choice. I take 2 inputs from user and when it tries to calculate, result can not be calculated because Var(x) can't be found. How can I make user's input as a variable in the function. I tried Var(x),Var[x] and Var$x but it didn't work. Thank you already.

```
findCrossProduct=function(x,y){

  print("which variables do you want to see the cross-product between ?")
  x=readline("Enter the first variable :")
  y=readline("Enter the second variable :")

  >> cp=sum(Var(x)*Var(y))-(sum(Var(x)*sum(Var(y))/length(Var(y)))) 

  print(paste("Cross-product betwen variable ",x,"and variable",y,"is",cp))

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `as.numeric(x)`?

Comment: I'm new at R actually. Can you give more details about usage of ```as.numeric(x)``` @RuiBarradas

Comment: After `readline` run `x <- as.numeric(x)` and the same for `y`. This is because `readline` return value is of class `"character"` and `sum` and `var` only work on numeric data. Note: R is case sensitive, it's `var`, not `Var`.

Answer (score 0):

The entire data frame should be called in the function.

```
findCrossProduct=function(df){

  print("which variables do you want to see the cross-product between?")

  x = readline("Enter the first variable: ")
  y = readline("Enter the second variable: ")

  cp = sum(df[x] * df[y]) - (sum(df[x])*sum(df[y])/nrow(df[y])) 

  print(paste("Cross-product between variable", x, "and variable", y, "is", cp))

}
```

The output is

```
> findCrossProduct(data)
[1] "which variables do you want to see the cross-product between?"
Enter the first variable: Var2
Enter the second variable: Var3
[1] "Cross-product between variable Var2 and variable Var3 is 0.200000000000045"
```

Ensure that the formula for cross product that I have used is correct.